# Open website using Url_launcher url_launcher: ^6.0.6

Tags: flutter, url

I am using   url_launcher: ^6.0.6 to launch a website by clicking on a link in my flutter app. It works by using Chrome (I am on an Android device emulator) but all of the phone controls disappear. I can't navigate back to the app or close Chrome.

What am I doing wrong?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

This is the code for the button:

```
    IconButton(
       icon: Icon(Icons.home),
       iconSize: 25,
       color: Colors.blueAccent,
       tooltip: 'View Property',
       onPressed: () {
       setState(() {
       _launched = _launchURL('https://www.utahrealestate.com/$_propertyMLSNbr');
                                });
                              },
                            ),
```

This is the code that opens the url:

```
 Future<void> _launchURL(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Like I said, this works but Chrome takes over my emulator. How do I fix this?

This is the url that I am opening:
https://www.utahrealestate.com/1750094

Comment: This works perfectly on iOS simulator as it opens every url inside the app!

Comment: I tried it on my actual device and it worked fine. I guess it was just the emulator that had problems.

Comment: Yup! so need to use `WebView` then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is the default behaviour of `url_launcher`, where URL is launched on browser in android where
You can use `WebView` instead!
run `flutter pub add webview_flutter` in terminal to add [WebView](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package.
Add this class where you want to use WebView :

```
class WebViewContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final _url;
  WebViewContainer(this._url);

  @override
  _WebViewContainerState createState() => _WebViewContainerState();
}

class _WebViewContainerState extends State<WebViewContainer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your WebView'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: WebView(
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              initialUrl: widget._url,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, simply put this in your onPressed method of your Icon Button to go to WebView page where a back icon will be available to come back to your main screen!

```
var url = 'https://www.utahrealestate.com/1750094';
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => WebViewContainer(url),
                      ),
                    );
```

Comment: I love that solution. Thank you for  bringing it to my attention.

Comment: Glad to help :)